# Auto stretching column width with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I think similar question must have been asked already, but I don't know how to find it...

I want to create a multi-column HTML layout with autostretching columns. Let's say 2 columns. When there's only one column on a page it fills 100% of container width, when I add a second column of 25% the first one automatically squeeze to 75%.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">...</div>
    <div class="sidebar">...</div>
</div>
```

I'm sure this can be done with JavaScript (checking if second column exists), but what about plain CSS? Is it actually possible? I need to support IE 9+.

Comment: Have you looked into using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)? You could then use a fallback for IE9.

Comment: @evolutionxbox, yes, but I need full IE9+ support, so flexbox won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with css selectors:

```
  .content{
    width:100%;
  }
  .sidebar{
    width:25%;
  }
  .content:not(:only-child){
    width:75%;
  }
```

Pen: http://codepen.io/vandervals/pen/zGqorj

I think this is far more elegant than the table solution and the support is really wide: http://caniuse.com/#search=only-child

Comment: I'd go with this solution personally. This way using display tables (which can cause responsive headaches) can be avoided.

Comment: I agree with you. But of course, in this case we have to be very carefull with what you put in the .wrapper, as the selection breaks when there are more children, even if they are not .sidebar

Answer (score 2):

You need something like following. Use `display:table` to parent and `display:table-cell` to child element.

```css
.wrapper{
    display:table;
    width: 100%;
}

.content{
    display:table-cell;
    background-color:yellow;
}

.sidebar{
    display:table-cell;
    width:25%;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">...</div>
    <div class="sidebar">...</div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I know you ask for a CSS solution, but here is a simple jQuery script to have a dynamic sizing (no matter the number of column, it will be divided and fit in the row).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.row').each(function(k, v) {
  var col =  $('.column', this),
   colNumber  = col.length,
   percent = 100 / colNumber;
   console.log(percent);
  col.css({'width' : percent + '%'});
 }); 
});
```

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
 width: 960px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.column {
 float: left;
 height: 200px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border: 1px solid black;
 background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="column"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```